# git aws.push to previous environment

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Git repository and I want to push it in an EC2 environment to update a website. It is the first time I want to do it, the previous pushing was made by an other developper.

But when I configure Elastic Beanstalk by `eb init`, he only propose me to create a new environment, not to connect to an existant one.

Is there a way to push to a previous environment when this environment was not created by my Elastic Beanstalk ?

Does I misunderstood the Elastic Beanstalk process ?

Thank you for your help !

Edit :
Ok, it works...
I must not use the `eb init` command but the `git aws.config` command with informations from the App and the environment.

Comment: Can your add an edit as an answer and accept your answer so that people know this has been resolved?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you are using v2.x of the CLI. v3 was released a couple weeks ago and has this ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it works... I must not use the eb init command but the git aws.config command with informations from the App and the environment.